# CSS using transform:scale() to make responsive html banner

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have very complex html banners. It would take days to apply media query and make it responsive. I was thinking to simply use javascript and css transform:scale(). Something like that:

```
parentWidth = $('#banner').parent().width();
bannerWidth = $('#banner').width();
if(parentWidth<=bannerWidth || originWidth>bannerWidth){
  rate = (originWidth-parentWidth)/originWidth;
  if(parentWidth>originWidth){
    scale = 1;
  }else{
    scale = 1-rate;
  }    
  $("#banner").css('transform','scale('+scale+')');
}
```

In this way it will act the same as if there was image for banner with width="100%". I am aware that some text will become very small. Other than that, is there any potential problem it could appear with different browsers? I tested this in my computer and it works fine, but I may not be aware about something.

tnx!

Comment: What is wrong with using the width 100% if it acts the same way?

Comment: 100% acts the same way if there is image as banner, in my case I have html banner with 20+ different elements such as h1,p,div with background images, ribbons, ...

Comment: ah ok, I see you have inner elements that need resizing with the banner - your question wasn't clear on that - it just seemed like you were resizing a banner image